# htaccess issue after connecting domain to subfolder

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, dns

I have a problem with .htaccess. I have a website in the main server folder and a domain that leads to it (adriatic.pl). No i have made a new version of the website and put it in "adriatic_new" folder. When i run adriatic.pl/adriatic_new/public everythig works fine, but when i connect the domain (adriatic.pl) directly to the "adriatic_new" folder I get "500 Internal Server Error".

I found that it may be .htaccess problem bo how to edit it to make it work?

It looks like this:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
Allow from all

DirectoryIndex main.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^/*$ static/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/static/%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule .* static/%{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/+$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ main.php [NC,L]

php_flag magic_quotes_qpc off
php_flag register_globals off
```

Comment: Did you check the contents of the apache error_log file to see why the 500 error is being generated?

Comment: I did now, and what i get is tens of errors like this "[Thu Nov 24 21:57:20 2011] [error] [client 80.239.22.30] script '/home/adriatic/ftp/adriatic_new/public/news.php' not found or unable to start"

Comment: I've been experimenting with htaccess and now when i go to some subpage like "http://adriatic.pl/pages/page/id/13" i get 404 file not found, bet when i type the url like this "http://adriatic.pl/index.php?pages/page/id/13" then it works just fine (whole webpage works if I add "index.php?".

Comment: You're using index.php in your comment but in your example you're using main.php. Try and rename main.php to index.php

Comment: I did and now i gaet "[Fri Nov 25 07:43:06 2011] [error] [client 87.205.180.214] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://adriatic.pl/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok guys (and ladies?) - problem is solved.

All I had to do was to add "RewriteBase /" in my .htaccess. So simple yet so confusing and annoying. Thanks.